# Neo4J Cypher: Count How Many Attributes/Properties in each node matched my query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example, lets say my query is:

> match (u:User) Where u.LivesIn:'Los Angeles' OR u.From:'Miami' OR
>   u.Status:'Single' OR u.Job:'Artist'}) return u

How would I change my query so I can display a column that counts how many attributes matched my query.

For my query above, lets say I returned the following Users:

```
> User1, Los Angeles, Miami, Single, Artist, (4 attributes matched query
> so show a 4 in column)
> 
> User2, Los Angeles, Miami, Married, Artist, (3 attributes matched
> query so display 3 in column)
> User3, Los Angeles, New York, Married, Dancer, (1 attributes matched
> query so display 1 in column)
```

Im using this to build a sort of ranking system

Im trying to get This:

> ```
> u.UserID     u.MatchingAttributes
>
> User1        4
>
> User2        3
>
> User3        1
> ```

Also as a bonus if you can please show how to do this with relationships also. Thanks.

Comment: it would be better if you would have modelled it as separate nodes instead of attribs\. Like single/married can be 2 nodes and newyork/LA can be 2 other nodes. All linked by relationships. Then you could easily do what you want..

Comment: Yes that sounds better, but i'm not sure how to write the same query using OR with relationships as you mention. But if I do use relationships, how would I count the matching Attributes?

Comment: instead of holding it as node attribs, you can create separate nodes which will be liked to the user node. Check my solution for a clearer understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a bunch of `CASE` statements:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WITH u.UserID AS User, CASE WHEN u.LivesIn = 'Los Angeles' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c1,
                       CASE WHEN u.From = 'Miami' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c2,
                       CASE WHEN u.Status = 'Single' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c3,
                       CASE WHEN u.Job = 'Artist' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS c4
RETURN User, c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 AS Matching
```

Comment: thats a pretty smart way !! nice!!

Comment: This is what I ended up using, also combining it with coalesce(for true/false) and reduce to add up the sum. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you graph is modelled as

[image]

Now you can name the relationships to something suitable. The sole purpose of the graph model i pasted is to just demostrate the matching strategy thats why i have skipped naming the relationships suitably and adding node labels.

Now what you can do is

```
match (u:User)-[r]-(m) where m.name in ['LA','Miami','Single','Artist'] return u,count(m) as count
```

{Assuming above the `m` other nodes (other than the User labelled nodes) have name attribs in them }

Comment: Thanks for the graph and reply. I ended up using Nicole's solution, but will make more use of neo4j relationships as you mention.

Comment: also i would suggest you to read about the underlying datastructure which neo4j uses to store attribs and how you can optimize retrieval of data .. because then you will realize why i was suggesting using relationships..